What is wrong with my view?
So I'm having issues with my view.  When I try to zoom in, the view doesn't go through objects no matter how far I zoom toward my selection.  I have no idea what to try, nor what to ask to get hints (I am not versed in all the words on the screen yet), so do you have any suggestions?
Thank ~



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Click the View tab down the R/H side of the 3D view and see how the Clip Start and End values are set. The defaults are 0.01 m  for Start and 1000 m for End. Try changing them and see if it helps.

Also try in Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan > check Auto Depth.

Changing the clip start value seemed to work!  I'm not sure what Auto Depth changed, but it didn't seem to impact my experience yet.  Thanks for the suggestions either way!!
